# Add annotations based on groups

Tags: r

I have a table as below. I am grouping my data and want to add annotations based on rel to a new column.So If Name, Dep, Loc match between Ind and Boss then add "Boss" to a new column. If Name, Dep, Loc match between Ind, Boss and Dir then add "Both" to a new column. If Name, Dep, Loc match between Ind and Dir then add "Dir: to the new column

```
mydata<-structure(list(Rec_id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), Name = c("A", 
"B", "A", "B", "B", "B"), Dep = c("abc", "abc", "abc", "def", 
"def", "def"), loc = c(123L, 456L, 123L, 888L, 888L, 888L), rel = c("Ind", 
"Ind", "Boss", "Ind", "Boss", "Dir")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Mycode:

```
mydata %>% 
group_by(Name, Dep, Loc) %>%
mutate(rel_from = ifelse()
```

Desired Output

```
Rec_id  Name    Dep loc rel rel_from
1   A   abc 123 Ind Boss
1   B   abc 456 Ind 
2   A   abc 123 Boss    
3   B   def 888 Ind Both
4   B   def 888 Boss    
5   B   def 888 Dir
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm inferring the need to add the string to only the rows that match `Ind`, still based on the other values of `rel` within the group.

```r
mydata %>%
  group_by(Name, Dep, loc) %>%
  mutate(
    rel_from = case_when(
      all(c("Ind", "Boss", "Dir") %in% rel) & rel == "Ind" ~ paste(rel, "Both"),
      all(c("Ind", "Boss") %in% rel)        & rel == "Ind" ~ paste(rel, "Boss"), 
      all(c("Ind", "Dir") %in% rel)         & rel == "Ind" ~ paste(rel, "Dir"),
      TRUE ~ rel
    )
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 6 × 6
#   Rec_id Name  Dep     loc rel   rel_from
#    <int> <chr> <chr> <int> <chr> <chr>   
# 1      1 A     abc     123 Ind   Ind Boss
# 2      1 B     abc     456 Ind   Ind     
# 3      2 A     abc     123 Boss  Boss    
# 4      3 B     def     888 Ind   Ind Both
# 5      4 B     def     888 Boss  Boss    
# 6      5 B     def     888 Dir   Dir
```